# Recover the coordinates of points on the real line from a distance matrix containing noise

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization

I encountered the following question in an interview. I haven't found an analytical solution to it.

**Problem Statement**

We are provided with the noisy estimates of signed differences $d_{ij}$ between a set of n real numbers $\{x_i\}$. Please find estimators $\{\hat{x_i}\}$ that minimize $\sum_{i,j}(d_{ij}-(\hat{x_i}-\hat{x_j}))^2$ subject to $min(\hat{x_i})=0$. The data is given as a skew-symmetric matrix, $D_{n \times n}=[d_{ij}]$, with $d_{ij} \approx x_i - x_j$.

**My Attempt**

First, we should determine which estimator is 0. For each $\hat{x_i}$, we can calculate the summation of distances from it to other points, i.e., $\sum_{1 \le j \le n} d_{ij}$. The $\hat{x_i}$ with the smallest summation of distances should be 0. It's the smallest because distances are signed.

We can estimate other numbers based on $d_{ij}$. Then we get a good starting point. We can fix the smallest $\hat{x_i}$, which is 0, and run gradient descent to find the global minima.

**My Question**

I guess there is an analytic solution. But I don't know how to find it. One possible way is to take the gradient and see when it becomes 0. But there are n+1 equations (n equations for n partial derivatives and 1 for $min(\hat{x_i})=0$), which I don't think always have a solution.

Does anyone know how to find the analytical solution?

By the way, if my intuition is correct, this question is somehow related to the Ordinary Least Squares problem, where we are looking for a "mean position" to minimize the loss. Is that so?